# Rails Url Generation Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a 2 models section and newsitem

section.rb

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :newsitems
end
```

newsitem.rb

```
class Newsitem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section
end
```

In section controller I have this:

```
class SectionsController < InheritedResources::Base
   defaults collection_name: 'sections', instance_name: 'section'

   def newsitems
      @newsitem = @section.newsitems
   end
end
```

In routes.rb

```
resources :sections
   resources :newsitems
```

In view I'm do this:

```
<% @newsitem.order('created_at DESC').each do |newsitem|  %>
    <div class="newsitem-block">
        <%= newsitem.created_at.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") %>
        <h1><%= link_to newsitem.title, newsitem %></h1>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

But rails show me error

```
No route matches {:type=>nil, :action=>"show", :controller=>"newsitems", :id=>nil, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id, :id]
```

rake routes:

```
                       newsitems GET      /offices(/:type)/:id/newsitems(.:format)                          newsitems#index {:type=>nil}
                                 POST     /offices(/:type)/:id/newsitems(.:format)                          newsitems#create {:type=>nil}
                    new_newsitem GET      /offices(/:type)/:id/newsitems/new(.:format)                      newsitems#new {:type=>nil}
                   edit_newsitem GET      /offices(/:type)/:id/newsitems/:id/edit(.:format)                 newsitems#edit {:type=>nil}
                        newsitem GET      /offices(/:type)/:id/newsitems/:id(.:format)                      newsitems#show {:type=>nil}
                                 PATCH    /offices(/:type)/:id/newsitems/:id(.:format)                      newsitems#update {:type=>nil}
                                 PUT      /offices(/:type)/:id/newsitems/:id(.:format)                      newsitems#update {:type=>nil}
                                 DELETE   /offices(/:type)/:id/newsitems/:id(.:format)                      newsitems#destroy {:type=>nil}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: type `rake routes` to view possible routes

Comment: I update post with log

Comment: `Are you sure,. All newsitem record has an id in the table?,. ` Please to check in the table once,.

Comment: Yes. If I render @newsitem.title without link, array is showing

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
<h1><%= link_to newsitem.title, [newsitem] %></h1>
```

or

```
<h1><%= link_to newsitem.title, newsitem_path(newsitem) %></h1>
```